# How to comment on instagram feed in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, instagram

I have follow the link instagram developer site and hit the api `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments` and sending parameter `text=testing..` for comments but I have got this response

```
 {
  "meta":  {
    "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "This request requires scope=comments, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=comments to be granted write permissions."
  }
}
```

and this:

```
Error Domain=instagramErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (instagramErrorDomain error 400.)" UserInfo=0xeb7ab40 {error_message=This client ID is not permitted to POST comments. For more info, please refer to our developer site at http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments., error_type=APIError}
```

Please any suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Dharmendra, Have you got any response from instagram? Have you got access to comment? I have exactly same problem. Please post your response. Thanks

Comment: Please note that instagram allow access to this endpoint solely for the following use cases:

1. A business requesting rights to media objects from the Instagram Community in order for the media to be used for display outside of Instagram.
2. A business providing customer service to members of the Instagram Community by interacting through comments.
3. A business responding to members of the Instagram Community that participate in a specific reward or coupon campaign.

Since your app doesn't appear to be serving any of these uses case, we're unable to grant access to the endpoint.
By Instagram

Comment: Developer Blog: http://developers.instagram.com/
    Bug Tool: https://help.instagram.com/contact/438525166257277      Above comments are mailed by instagram regarding the Request access to comments POST endpoint

Comment: Thanks for your time, Dharmendra. Thanks for reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be 2 reason for this.

1) You need to post valid acessToken in your request.

2) Your app is not authorised to post comment. You have to request Instragram to allow your app to post comment.

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/

Comment: Thanks for the answers but i am authorising my application with scope=likes+comments+relationships+basic and I am able to get feeds,post feed,like,unlike feeds,and relationship functionality.so,it is also a valid token. but i am not able to comments.please suggest.

Comment: For comments, you have to request the instragram api to allow your app to authorised to post comment. You have to fill this form to allow app to post comment. https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

Comment: Thank. I have fill the form that you had provide the link https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116. How much time instagram will take to review it and contact to me. so, that i am enable to post a comment.

Comment: I want to posted a comment which is sent by Instagram Platform Team :- Hello,

Thank you again for your interest in the comments POST endpoint.

We have reviewed your application and have determined that your request does not comply with our requirements for usage of this endpoint. Please note that we allow access to this endpoint solely for the following use cases:

1. A business requesting rights to media objects from the Instagram Community in order for the media to be used for display outside of Instagram.

Comment: 2. A business providing customer service to members of the Instagram Community by interacting through comments.
3. A business responding to members of the Instagram Community that participate in a specific reward or coupon campaign.


Since your app doesn't appear to be serving any of these uses case, we're unable to grant access to the endpoint.

Thanks,
Instagram Platform Team

Developer Blog: http://developers.instagram.com/
Bug Tool: https://help.instagram.com/contact/438525166257277